# python: cannot find module in the package

Tags: python, python-import

I am creating a python project with the following directory structure:

```
demos
   demo1.py
kernels
   rbf.py
   ___init__.py
```

The file `rbf.py` defines a class called `RBF`. The `__init__.py` file in the `kernels` directory contains the following line:

```
from .rbf import *
```

Now the `demo1.py` contains the following import:

```
from kernels import RBF
```

However, this fails with

```
ImportError: No module named kernels
```

So the `demos` folder does not see the `kernels` package directory. I am at a loss as to what to do to make this work.

Comment: Are you running the demo1.py script from the top-level directory (python demos/demo1.py)?

Comment: I ran from demos directory and the top level directory but I got the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the parent directory of `kernels` to either `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or directly to `sys.path` for Python to be able to find the package `kernels` .

Example of modifying `sys.path` in `demo1.py` , assuming both `demo` and `kernels` have the same parent directory -

```
import os, os.path
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..')))
from kernels import RBF
```

What the above does -

`__file__` gets the path of the script

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` - gets the path of the directory containing the file.

`os.path.join()` - creates the path like - `/path/to/demos/..` - depending on the OS.

`os.path.abspath` - gets the absolute path of the parent directory from `/path/to/demos/..`

Comment: Ah ok... Is this very standard thing to do? I never see that in any online python projects....??? Perhaps they take care of it in the setup.py files?

Comment: Yes , there are some directories that come up automatically in sys.path , you can try printing it to see what they are . When you install a library , most of the times , they install in the correct directory such that users do not have to add it to PYTHONPATH or sys.path separately .

Answer (score 0):

If both the demo1 and kernels are not in the same folder, you have to add the path to kernels file to the `path` environmental variable.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/kernels")
```